# I need to modify this MVC list object in VB

Tags: vb.net, razor

I trying convert this list of object in MVC to VB. But, I feel difficult to convert the MVC code as VB code.As, I am very new VB.net.

```
@{List<Object> Special = new List<Object>() { "3/12/2017", "3/18/2017" };}
```

when use the same tag , it show "Object need end tag" message. Please,  help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You mean this? `Dim MyList As New List(Of Object)` then you can just use `MyList.Add("3/12/2017")` But you could use: `List(Of String)`

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of converter C# to VB like http://converter.telerik.com/ to help you specially for these simple line of code

Comment: I have tried with that link you suggested but is throwing error, could you please help me to convert it. It would be very helpful to me

Comment: Have you tried Dim Special As New List(Of [Object])() From { "3/12/2017", "3/18/2017" } ?